# Contextual menu on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm facing a little problem with my code :

```
<style>
.btn_remove{
    position:absolute;  
    right:-25px;                        
}
.test:hover > table{
    background-color:#708ab3;           
}
</style>


<a href="page/ABC" class="test" ng-mouseenter="showRemove = true" ng-mouseleave="showRemove = false">   
<div class="btn_remove" ng-show="showRemove"><img src="../../gfx/btn_remove.png" height="28" width="26" border="0"/></div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>mercedes class a</td>
            <td>70'000</td>
        </tr>               
        <tr>
            <td><i>Nice car</i></td>
            <td>Color: Red</td>                         
        </tr>                               
    </table>    
</a>
```

So as you can see I have a table into a `<a href>`. When I pass my mouse over the table it calls the class `.test:hover > table` and also set the angular variable `showRemove = true` which will then show the `absolute div` on the right of the table.

My problem is when I mouse over the absolute div, it has the href from the parent `(page/ABC)`. 
If I try to write 
`<div class="btn_remove" ng-show="showRemove"><a href="remove"><img src="../../gfx/btn_remove.png" height="28" width="26" border="0"/></a></div>`
then nothing is working because the first link isn't closed.

How could i manage to get :

- Mouseover on table = background change + link (page/ABC) + show remove image on the right.
- Mouseover on remove image = JS function to be called or whatever but do not be part of the parent link.
- Mouseout of table or remove image = remove "remove image" and remove background change.

All this without using jquery. JS or angular, but i guess it's mostly div and css.

[image: Wanted result]

Solution:

```
<style>
.test{
    position:absolute;  
    right:-25px;
    visibility:hidden;                      
}
.wrapper:hover table{
    background-color:#708ab3;           
}
.wrapper:hover .test
{
   visibility:visible;   
}
</style>
<div class="wrapper">                           
    <div class="test"><a href="remove"><img src="../../gfx/btn_remove.png" height="28" width="26" border="0"/></a></div>
    <a href="table link">                       
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Mercedes Class A</td>
            <td>70'000</td>
        </tr>               
        <tr>
            <td><i>Nice car</i></td>
            <td>Red</td>                            
        </tr>                               
    </table>    
    </a>
</div>
<hr/>
```

Comment: Why is the link applied to the entire table?

Comment: Because i need to. I use a table for each type of data i need to display. So globally i have a a global div which contains multiple table inside

Comment: So the issue you are having is that you want two links one around the table and the other around the image; but because the image is inside the first anchor it is not registering the images click?

Comment: Yes that's right and it also disable the entire action because it's like have <a href=""> <div> <a href="another link"> <img> </a> </div> </a>

Comment: No you don't need to.  Putting a table inside of an A tag isn't valid HTML, so I'd abandon that to make sure that you get cross-browser compatibility and that everything works as expected.  You can still get mouseover functionality without attaching the event to the A tag.  But I'm still unclear on what you're trying to do.  If you let us know that, we can provide a better answer.

Comment: I agree with dave I'm not entirely sure why you have the table in a link; You can hover any element now a'days and it will work fine.

But assuming you are just trying to style the elements and not links you should be able to do it like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/jE7J6/

Then if you really need a link around the table you can just add it; should still work

Comment: Just edited with image of wanted result

Comment: So the image link is to hide the table row?

Comment: Toby, thanks for you fiddle, i get it work will update my question with result. YOu can post the result as answer and so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to hear you got it working.

for reference you can add javascript:; to the href of an anchor to make it not do anything.

You can select a child element on hover using:

```
.parent:hover .child
{
the hover styles for the child
}
```

here is the fiddle for anyone else who needs to select a child element on hover [jsfiddle.net/jE7J6](http://jsfiddle.net/jE7J6)